# How to remove white spaces from string between the comma "," and any letters in java

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file which has the following data:

```
1, what is your name, male, cell no
```

I want this as:

```
1,what is your name,male,cell no
```

How can I remove the space after the comma there?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do, here?

Comment: Meanwhile i want to remove square brackets at beginning and ending of string..

Comment: You want comma or not?

Comment: I would like to remove square brackets from beginning and end of a string, if they are existing.

[Just a string] /n Just a string /n Just a string [comment]/n [Just a string [comment]] 

Should result in

Just a string/n Just a string/n Just a string [comment]/n Just a string [comment] 

I tried to build an regex, but I don't get it in a correct way, as it doesn't look for the position:

Comment: That comma thing worked.now stucked in this problem.

Comment: please add the same explanation in your question, I'll post the solution.

Comment: Can you share any way to contact you through social media?we are in last steps of our fyp and now stucked really bad at few points

Comment: If not, i will update my question soon.and will comment here again so you are notified.

Comment: Update your question here, like what if the input is like `[1,2,3[4,5,6]`, what do you expect here?

Comment: My list<string> contain data which has square bracket just at the start and the end. It doesn't contain square bracket in between

Comment: Can you check if this works for you ```String text = "[1,2,3],[123],[123]".replaceAll("],","]\n").replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("\\]","");```

Comment: Working.Thanks alot brother.

Comment: Please upvote my asnwer.

Comment: comments cannot be up voted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `String.replaceAll`, replace `],` with `]` and `\n` for linebreak

```
 String input = " [1,2,3],[123],[123]";
 input = input.replaceAll("],", "]\n");
 System.out.println("after removing comma:"+input);
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3][123][123]
```

Comment: use input = input.replaceAll("],", "]\n"); if you want line breaks

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
String text = "[1,2,3],[123],[123]";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(?<=\\])\\,(?=\\[)", "\n"));
```

In the cases where you want to replace something you need to match just that character(s) in this case `,`, but to recognize which character it is you need to match ones around it. These situations are perfect for `lookahead` and `lookbehind` which can be `positive` and `negative` depending on what you need. They match characters around the one you're trying to find, but are not part of the match.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many simpler ways.

```
    String input = "[1,2,3],[123],[123]";
    input = input.replaceAll("],", "] ");
    
    String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(inputArray[i]);
    }
```